# Cannot import custom NodeJs module in Vue component

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, commonjs

I am building a webservice with Node and Vue. I built backend Node modules which are all working as expected. But when I try to import those in my Vue SFC script, I am getting 'stream undefined' error.

My hunch is that I am mixing CommonJS and ES6 styles of exporting and importing and that is causing the issue because when I created a temporary module with just one function and no require or import statements and use module.exports to expose that function and then call import in Vue SFC, it is working. But when I use require statements in the module, I am getting the stream undefined error again. I tried multiple solutions I found online but I am not able to get it to work.

My (temporary) node module, temp.js. This doesn't work:

```
require('./auth.js');

function test(){
  console.log('Test method');
}

module.exports = {test};
```

This works:

```
function test(){
  console.log('Test method');
}

module.exports = {test};
```

My SFC script:

```
<script>
import * as temp from './temp.js';

export default {
  name: 'Dashboard'
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think when you require something it has to be set as a local variable. So `const auth = require('./auth.js');`. That being said, you never reference `auth.js` in your module, so why bother requiring it? Is `test` a function within `auth.js`?

Comment: @LenJoseph I simplified my code significantly for the sake of this question. I intend to use `auth.js` (just not shown here) but just calling `require` is breaking the code. `test` is a function in `temp.js` which is also a temporary file I created for the sake of this question.

Comment: I think the problem is that you aren't binding your require statement to a variable. typically you will bind a dependency to a local constant, common example is `const app = require('express');` in the node environment, for example. Then you have full access to express interface (`app.use()`, `app.options()`, etc.). Also, make sure you are exporting properly within `auth.js`.

Comment: @LenJoseph Binding the return value of `require` shouldn't change anything. `require` function is called even if you bind its return value to a variable or not. But just for the sake of it, I changed it to `const auth = require('./auth.js');` and it still doesn't work. As to exporting in `auth.js`, I am using `module.exports = ...` there too.